# How to insert data from raspberry to blockchain

Tags: storage

My aim is to make n raspberry as nodes of a blockchain (obviously using ethereum),whose purpose is only and exclusively data storage.
I've chosen Python as script language.
I installed pytheapp on my  i-th raspberry  and I followed this tutorial https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/wiki/Getting-Started.
Now,once it has become a node and it is synchronized with the blockchain,how do I manage to store those data in the blokchain??(In my case data are few strings: some sets of ID,gps coordinates and date + hours )
Thank you evrybody for your answers and I apologize for my english ahah

---

Thank you for your answers.I'm trying to follow your advices,but I am pretty confused...Could you suggest me some material,links or what else,that can introduce to the basics of these arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a conceptual overview.

As an Ethereum node, the Raspberry would be a full participant in the network. In the context of Ethereum, it would have accounts and private keys for signing transactions and it would be able to do the same things as a human participant; no more and no less.

In summary, the Raspberry (Python, Node, etc.) would gather data and then send a transaction to the interested contract. That contract would have a `function` that expects the received data and does something with it such as storing the data permanently on the blockchain. In the context of that `function`, the `msg.sender` would be the Raspberry account that signed the transaction.

There is discussion of allowing contracts to pay for their own gas in the future. At present, sender always pays so the Raspberry will need a small amount of Ether. Send a little Ether to the Raspberry's account. The Raspberry's balance can be checked & topped up without actual access to the device. All that is required is knowledge of its address.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

send a transaction to yourself or another account with the data you want to save in the data field (`msg.value`).